# How to get this listing layout in LaTeX

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I was reading this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.03532.pdf), which appears to be written and generated from `LaTeX`, how, can you make something like the below in `LaTeX`. My setup: `\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,11pt]{article}`. **Three or multi-column** listing, I want to list `keywords` this way.

[image]

**From source:**

```
\begin{figure}[t]
  \small
\begin{synchart*}{syn}
  %
  %
  %
  \Sort{Typ} & \tau & \bnfdef & \qrefty{q}             & \blue{\qrefty{q}}                          & \text{qubit reference} \\
             &      & \bnfalt & \arrty{\tau_1}{\tau_2} & \blue{\arrty*{\blk{\tau_1}}{\blk{\tau_2}}} & \text{function} \\
             &      & \bnfalt & \cmdty{\tau}           & \blue{\cmdty*{\blk{\tau}}}                 & \text{command} \\
             &      & \bnfalt & \vprodty{\tau}         & \blue{\vprodty*{\blk{\tau_i}}}             & \text{variadic product} \\
             &      & \bnfalt & \boolty                & \blue{\boolty}                             & \text{boolean} \\
             &      & \bnfalt & \unitty                & \blue{\unitty}                             & \text{unit} \\[1ex]
  \Sort{Exp} & e & \bnfdef & x                    & x                                              & \text{variable} \\
             &   & \bnfalt & \letbnd{e_1}{x}{e_2} & \blue{\letbnd*{\blk{e_1}}{x}{\blk{e_2}}}       & \text{let binding} \\
             &   & \bnfalt & \lamex{x}{e}         & \blue{\lamex*{x}{\blk{e}}}                     & \text{function} \\
             &   & \bnfalt & \appex{e_1}{e_2}     & \blue{\appex*{\blk{e_1}}{\blk{e_2}}}           & \text{application} \\
             &   & \bnfalt & \cmdex{m}            & \blue{\cmdex*{\blk{m}}}                        & \text{encapsulated command} \\
             &   & \bnfalt & \vtupleex{e}         & \blue{\vtupleex*{\blk{e}}}                     & \text{tuple} \\
             &   & \bnfalt & \vprojex{e}          & \blue{\vprojex*{\blk{e}}}                      & \text{projection} \\
             &   & \bnfalt & \trueex              & \blue{\trueex*}                                & \text{true} \\
             &   & \bnfalt & \falseex             & \blue{\falseex*}                               & \text{false} \\
             &   & \bnfalt & \ifex{e}{e_1}{e_2}   & \blue{\ifSugar{\blk{e}}{\blk{e_1}}{\blk{e_2}}} & \text{if expression} \\
             &   & \bnfalt & \unitex              & \blue{\unitex*}                                & \text{unit} \\[1ex]
  \Sort{Cmd} & m & \bnfdef & \retcmd{e}              & \blue{\retcmd*{\blk{e}}}                    & \text{return} \\
             &   & \bnfalt & \bndcmd{e}{x}{m}        & \blue{\bndcmd*{\blk{e}}{x}{\blk{m}}}        & \text{bind} \\
             &   & \bnfalt & \newcmd{x}{m}           & \blue{\newcmd*{x}{\blk{m}}}                 & \text{new qubit reference} \\
             &   & \bnfalt & \gateap{U}{e}           & \blue{\gateap*{U}{\blk{e}}}                 & \text{gate application} \\
             &   & \bnfalt & \diagap{U}{V}{e_1}{e_2} & \blue{\diagap*{U}{V}{\blk{e_1}}{\blk{e_2}}} & \text{diagonal gate application}   \\
             &   & \bnfalt & \meascmd{e}             & \blue{\meascmd*{\blk{e}}}                   & \text{measure}
\end{synchart*}
  \caption{Abstract and concrete syntax of \core.}
  \label{fig:abssyntax}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: you do not need to guess how it was done the tex source is available https://arxiv.org/format/2206.03532